Kibana Query for Message that contains ":"
I have the following documents in Kibana
document1: LogStatus ApplicationA:X ApplicationB:O ApplicationC:O
document2: LogStatus ApplicationA:O ApplicationB:O ApplicationC:O
document3: LogStatus ApplicationD:O ApplicationE:O ApplicationF:O

Note: X means stopped, O means running
I wanted to search for documents that contains message LogStatus and :X. For example above, I want to get document1.
I tried this query: message:*LogStatus* and message: *:X*
However, since ":" is special character in KQL as equals, it returns error.
Any idea how to search message that contains ":"?

Did you try this message:*LogStatus* and message:*\:X* ?

@RakeshGovindula it works! Thank you!

Converting my comment into an answer. Here, : is a special character. As you did the search with a special character, you got the above error. To search a string which is involving a special character, you need to escape it.
You can use \ as an escape character here to escape the special character : in your string.
Modify the query like below to search for LogStatus and :X.
message:*LogStatus* and message:*\:X*

Now, it will escape the : and will search for the required :X string in each document.
Sample demo:
Here, you can see it escaped the : in the below query and got the expected results.
container.image.name : *confluentinc/cp-kafka\:5.0.1*


